# What's difference between activiti setAssignee and claim API?

Tags: activiti

I was wondering what are the difference between these two APIs. Looks like setAssignee is fine grained while claim is a coarse grained. Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 1):

Difference between these methods is mentioned in [Javadocs of Activiti.](http://activiti.org/javadocs)

[void claim(String taskId, String userId):](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/TaskService.html#claim%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> The difference with setAssignee(String, String) is that here a check is done if the task > already has a user assigned to it. No check is done whether the user is known by the identity component.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering my own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Had a look at the claim's method source code, below are the excerpts:

```
if (!task.getAssignee().equals(userId))
{
    throw new ActivitiTaskAlreadyClaimedException(task.getId(), task.getAssignee());
}
else
{
    task.setAssignee(userId);
}      
commandContext.getHistoryManager().recordTaskClaim(taskId);
```

Quite evident from above, this is the extra done with claim:

1. exception thrown if the task already assigned
2. logs the history of claimed task